# Netapp Storage to HP Nimble cloud

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, storage, hp, netapp

We have a working Netapp Setup with FAS2720 9.7P9 Version connected to Fujitsu ESXi (VMWare 5.5). With multiple VMs running on 3 ESXi Systems but they are residing entirely on Netapp Storage.

We are thinking of moving this entire setup to private Cloud using HP Nimble cloud storage. This cloud is currently owned by one of our departments and are ready to give us space(in terms of storage) and ESXis(VMI Cluster) to run our VMs on a rental basis. So immediate advantage for us is more space, more network speed, DR Setup and not anymore worry about the hardware. Their hardware consists of Nimble Cluster Storage, Synergy 12000 Blades.

Of course it is in the discussion phase but I still would like to ask you experts following questions.

1. Is this really so advisable the way it is projected?
2. Netapp Storage does support cloud. So technically it should be possible to migrate the data. What is the best strategy for this? Do we require additional licenses?
3. Netapp Storage is all about data plus its configuration (Snapshot, User Quota Policies, Export Rules etc.). When we talk about storage space in cloud, then how are we going to control/administrate the configuration parts listed above? Or will this not be anymore possible to administrate on our own? And the Cloud administrators take Full control in their hands and we have to be dependent on them for every configuration changes? This is very important factor.
4. Will VMs running on Netapp Storage be migrated without much efforts? Is there any documented method for this?

Your view on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is this really so advisable the way it is projected?

Yeah, sounds good, you're running on a very old version of ESXi, so presumably there environment is running on fully-supported infrastructure - the only complex bit is making sure their networking is designed to support your current workloads.

> 2. Netapp Storage does support cloud. So technically it should be
>    possible to migrate the data. What is the best strategy for this? Do
>    we require additional licenses?

Not quite sure what you mean by 'does support cloud' - but anyway...if you can afford the downtime then just shutdown your VMs where they are - copy them to some form of portable storage, get the storage to the new place, copy them onto the new infrastructure, start them up, make and required changes (IP/DN/NTP/DNS etc.), profit. Of course this then gives you the ability to just failback to the original setup by restarting the current VMs.

> 3. Netapp Storage is all about data plus its configuration (Snapshot,
>    User Quota Policies, Export Rules etc.). When we talk about storage
>    space in cloud, then how are we going to control/administrate the
>    configuration parts listed above? Or will this not be anymore possible
>    to administrate on our own? And the Cloud administrators take Full
>    control in their hands and we have to be dependent on them for every
>    configuration changes? This is very important factor.

I'm really not sure what you're getting at here, the new place's staff will manage the storage, it'll be invisible to you.

> 4. Will VMs running on Netapp Storage be migrated without much efforts?
>    Is there any documented method for this?

You'll need to plan, mostly around those things I've mentioned above, but yeah it can work, so long as you do that - also of use is the concept of creating a testing VM on the new infrastructure - just a plain VM that you can make roughly behave like the ones you're moving over to test things like connectivity. It'd help build confidence and can be removed once you move your actual Production VMs over.